# Как вывести данные из 4-х таблиц 1 SQL запросом?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть 4 связанные таблицы Ассортимент с полями: код изделия, название изделия, вид изделия,жирность,код производителя, вес, цена производителя, цена продажи.Таблица Производители с полями: код производителя, название производителя, телефон ФИО директора, адрес. Таблица Заказы с  полями: номер заказа, код производителя, дата заказа. Таблица Содержимое заказа с полями: номер заказа, код изделия, количество  и я хочу 1 SQL запросом вывести данные по определенным условиям Таблица Ассортимент:название изделия,цена производителя, цена магазина.Таблица заказ:номер заказа и дата заказа Таблица Содержимое заказа: количество товара.Производитель: название производителя. Я пробовал через UNION, но там нужно одинаковое количество столбцов и еще чтобы одинаковый тип данных был, ребят, подскажите пожалуйста какой еще способ есть вывести все данные 1 запросом?

Comment: Очень желательно добавить в вопрос описание таблиц из которых надо получить информацию. И какую именно информацию нужно получить.

Comment: При помощи `JOIN`

Comment: Вложенные запросы, называется такой метод( select внутри select)

Comment: @rodgers , Господи, нет, нет нет НЕТ НЕЕЕЕЕЕЕТ. Вообще даже знать не нужно людям о существовании вложенных запросов, я серьезно. Пока не разберутся с UNION и JOIN. Тонны ужаса генерируются этими вашими "вложенными запросами".

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а как правильно тогда можно оформить вопрос?

Comment: Правильно понял, нужно вывести `данные из таблицы 1` `данные из таблицы 2` `данные из таблицы 3` - подряд, без связи между ними? Вот зачем? Экономите на запросах? Пытаетесь сделать финт ушами? Это тестовое задание? Полагаю, это ошибочный путь, сделайте три отдельных запроса

Comment: Я их уже связал в phpmyAdmin

Comment: Да. это тестовое задание

Comment: `Я их уже связал в phpmyAdmin` если вы решили проблему, просьба опубликовать решение. Если нет, тогда предоставьте схему БД, запрос без знания столбцов не написать

Comment: Извините пожалуйста за такой вопрос, а как графически вывести схему базу данных в phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему таким запросом:

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT name_product,id_order,date_order,amount,price_producer,price_sale,name_producer  FROM assortment,oreder_content,orders,producers WHERE id_order="'.$number.'" 
 AND name_product="'.$product.'" AND name_producer="'.$producer.'" AND amount="'.$count.'"';
```